# get exact difference between two files in different servers

Tags: windows, command-line

I have two files in windows server,I  want to compare these two files and get the exact difference between two and write the same in one file and mail it to my email id.

I want to run this command in command line/non-gui mode.

Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Comment: What commands have you tried thus far?

Comment: FC...it does have different arguments but those are not helpful